# Is there a smudge tool for grease pencil in v3.2?

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm trying to see if v3.2 has a similar tool like the smudge tool in photoshop to blend colors together. I have several different colors I'm using for my drawing/painting and they are set up as materials. Is it possible to smudge the colors/materials together or is that not a feature yet in grease pencil?

Thanks!

Comment: Grease pencil doesn’t work like that. It’s more like vector graphics. Each stroke stays unique, unlike the sandbox of pixels that happens in a bitmap. You might be able to get an effect something like this by making strokes semitransparent, but we’d really need to know exactly what you were trying to do.

Comment: Here is what i'm trying to do. I've drawn a picture with grease pencil and now i would like to color it in, to add shadows and highlights to give some depth to the drawing, like you would do when you are painting/coloring a picture. So that comes back to my original question, is that something you can do in blender? If not, it seems like then all you could do for any type of 2d picture/2d animation is have it in black and white or add a single fill color to it or am i missing something?

Comment: No drawing was added to the question. I recommend you look at examples and tutorials of grease pencil blender animation.